# How does a program receive a signal?

Tags: signals, theory

Theoretical question: Let's say that I open up Skype and my friend calls me. How does Skype know that someone's calling me? Was it checking for calls (signals) every second?

> Skype: Is someone calling?
>
> Server: No.
>
> Skype: Is someone calling?
>
> Server: No.
>
> Skype: Is someone calling?
>
> Server: Yes.
>
> Skype: Alright, hook us up.

Surely there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Skype is actually implemented. Hopefully, that was not the intent of the question. Here is a super high-level description of how this might work.

One way it might work is this:

- You are running a server
- The server is listening on a socket
- While listening, the server is blocked (doing nothing)
- When info arrive for your socket, the OS signals your server
- Once signaled, the server accepts the info and responds appropriately

This may or may not be a realistic depiction of what is going on in your particular case. Another possibility is this:

- You are running a client
- There is a remote server running
- You establish a session with the remote server and start listening
- While listening, the client is blocked (doing nothing)
- The server is listening on a socket
- While listening, the server is blocked (doing nothing)
- When packets arrive for your Skype client, the remote OS signals the server
- Once signaled, the server starts a new thread to handle your request
- It figures out the packets it got were associated with your session, and sends them
- When these info arrive at your local OS, it signals your client
- Once signaled, the client accepts the info and responds appropriately

Pictures of each method:

```
    SKYPE     __________________   ????????
(local server)                  (remote client)



    SKYPE     _________     SERVER    ________   ???????
(local client)         (remote server)        (remote client)
```

In both cases, polling is not required provided the operating systems involved support multiprogramming (multiple processes overlapping execution, not necessarily truly in parallel), in which case these processes can block on I/O until signaled by the OS.

Fundamentally, though, multiprogramming with blocking on I/O is a lot like polling in the sense that the process scheduler is polling every time it makes a decision about which process gets the next time quantum.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer. Follow-up question: What's happening on the lowest level when the server is listening? Is it constantly checking whether the signal is received or not? Excuse my ignorance and limited understanding.

Comment: @Phil I probably could have explained this better in my answer. Here's what I expect typically happens on systems with multiprogramming operating systems. First, the thread registers itself as listening on a socket. This is some flag associated with the thread. Then, it the task scheduler schedules some other threads while our thread is waiting to hear something. When the network card receives data, it signals the OS (e.g., by interrupt) that the data is available. The task scheduler recognizes this, the thread's flag is cleared and it is scheduled as per normal.